# Tokens in TFS 2018

Tags: tfs

I was checking Token options in TFS 2018 when I realize that If I create a Personal access token I only have a few options for the expiration: 1 year, 180 days or 90 days.

What happens if I choose 1 year? Can I renew it?
Or is it possible to create tokes with an higher duration?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once a token expires, you have to generate a new one. You cannot extend it. One year is the maximum. If you need an authentication option that is renewable, use [an OAuth token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/integrate/get-started/authentication/oauth?view=azure-devops).